# jsPDF Non-strict equality warning

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I deployed my build in the environment and I got this warning in Jenkins, any idea what it is ?

```
WARNING in Terser Plugin: Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js:86,67647]
```

Looking at that file at the exact line I see this:

```
set:function(t){t=t.toString(),f=this instanceof mt==!1?"("===t.substr(0,1)?T(t.substr(1,t.length-2)):T(t):t}})
```

However, that file unminified looks like this:

```
set: function set(value) {
  value = value.toString();

  if (this instanceof AcroFormButton === false) {
    if (value.substr(0, 1) === "(") {
      _DV = pdfUnescape(value.substr(1, value.length - 2));
    } else {
      _DV = pdfUnescape(value);
    }
  } else {
    _DV = value;
  }
}
```

So I am assuming that the problem is here `mt==!1?` in the minified version while on the unminified we have `if (this instanceof AcroFormButton === false)`. It seems that in the minified version we have `==` not strict, I am only assuming that this can be the issue but I don't understand why because I did not make any change in the library.

Comment: Are you running Terser on the output of a minifier (maybe even its own output) by mistake?

Comment: To be honest, it was already configured in the project by somebody else. It's the first time I hear of the Terser plugin. How can I check if what you said is true or false ? Normally terser should not check in the dependencies ? Where do I configure that ? Thx